# setInterval inside .each() only working for last interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, each, countdown

**Goal:**

Im looping through several .event elements using jQuery's each function. I am calculating a timer countdown using information coming from hidden span elements inside each .event class. I am using setInterval() to recalculate the remaining time every second.

**Problem:**

All my calculations work perfectly – but only for the last interval. Each interval seems to overwrite the calculation from the one before. Meaning: only the last .event is even getting an output. All previous .event are not even getting any output. Using logs before and after the interval, I was able to narrow my error down to the setInterval function. How can I prevent each interval from overwriting the one before? Or is my error somewhere I did not even think of yet?

**Code:**

```
$('.event').each(function() {
    $event = $(this);

    // SET FUTURE DATE
    $futureDate = $event.find($('.event-time'));
    $countdownDate = new Date($futureDate.text()).getTime();

    setInterval(function() {
    
        // SET TODAYS DATE
        $now = new Date().getTime();
    
        // DIFFERENCE NOW AND FUTURE DATE
        $diff = $countdownDate - $now;
    
        // TIME CALCULATIONS FOR d, h, m, s
        $days = Math.floor($diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        $hours = Math.floor(($diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        $minutes = Math.floor(($diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        $seconds = Math.floor(($diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
        // OUTPUT
        $event.find('.clock .val-d').html($days);
        $event.find('.clock .val-h').html($hours);
        $event.find('.clock .val-m').html($minutes);
        $event.find('.clock .val-s').html($seconds);
    
    }, 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because when the function within your interval runs the loop has finished, so `$event` will only ever refer to the last `.event` element in the jQuery object.

The simple fix for this, assuming you can use ES6, is to use the `let` keyword to define the `$event`:

```
$('.event').each(function() {
  let $event = $(this);

  // the rest of your code...
});
```

If you can't use ES6 then you'll need to use a closure to retain the scope of `$(this)`:

```js
$('.event').each(function() {
  (function($event) {
    $futureDate = $event.find($('.event-time'));
    $countdownDate = new Date($futureDate.text()).getTime();

    setInterval(function() {
      $now = new Date().getTime();
      $diff = $countdownDate - $now;

      // TIME CALCULATIONS FOR d, h, m, s
      $days = Math.floor($diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      $hours = Math.floor(($diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      $minutes = Math.floor(($diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      $seconds = Math.floor(($diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      $event.find('.clock .val-d').html($days);
      $event.find('.clock .val-h').html($hours);
      $event.find('.clock .val-m').html($minutes);
      $event.find('.clock .val-s').html($seconds);
    }, 1000)
  })($(this));
});
```

Comment: Using your second approach, all .event now get an ouput – but all get the same timer. Each .event has an own countdown timer and should therefore get his own outputs. What am I missing?

Comment: If you can't use ES6, can't you simply use `var $event = $(this);` instead?

Comment: @Ivar this actually did gave me the same result, yes. But still, every .event gets the same countdown timer, not its individual

Comment: @Sandro Add `var` in front of `$futureDate` and `$countdownDate` as well. You should (with some exceptions) always declare your variables using `var`/`let`/`const`. If you don't, they become global variables which can cause issues like these.